# Twitter bootstrap carousel control with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to find the best solution for Twitter Bootstrap Carousel 2.3 navigation control but I could not find any. The case is as following. I am trying to trigger carousel from **one button** but until now I haven't found the right solution. I know that I need to toogle carousel classes but how I really don't know.

Here is jquery which I am using right now:

```
            $(function () {
            $('.modal-carousel').carousel({
                interval:2000,
                pause: "false"
            });
            $('.style').click(function () {
                $('.modal-carousel').carousel('cycle');
                console.log('Starts carousel');
            });
            $('.stop.style').click(function () {
                $('.modal-carousel').carousel('pause');
                console.log('Stops carousel');
            });
        });
```

The button has always **.style class** while **.stop** is added when user click on the button.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hasClass` to determine `stop` class on element and use it toogle corousel state and don't have to bind the element twice.
like this

```
    $(function () {
        $('.modal-carousel').carousel({
            interval:2000,
            pause: "false"
        });

        $('.style').click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("stop")){
                $('.modal-carousel').carousel('pause');
                console.log('Stops carousel');   
            } else {
                $('.modal-carousel').carousel('cycle');
                console.log('Starts carousel');
            }            
        });
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Somewhere in js you've made mistake but I can not find it... it breaks all my js with this snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer which is working in my case so you can try both:

```
        $(function () {
              $('.modal-carousel').carousel('pause');

              $('.style').click(function () {
                  if ($(this).hasClass("stop")){
                      $('.modal-carousel').carousel({
                            pause: true,
                            interval: 0
                        });
                      console.log('Stops carousel');   
                  } else {
                      $('.modal-carousel').carousel({
                            pause: true,
                            interval: 3000
                        });
                      console.log('Starts carousel');
                  }            
              });
        });
```